# tkinter import added to my python script in VS Code

Tags: python, tkinter

I am writing a python script in VS Code and noticed the other day that "from tkinter import W" was at the top of my file above "def main()".  I found it odd since I have never used tkinter so I commented out the line. Now today I see the same line added at the top of my code, below the commented out line. How is this being added to my code without my knowledge of it happening?

```
#from tkinter import W

from tkinter import W
```

Comment: this question is not related to tkinter, but vscode. My best guess is that the intellisense did it. When you typed `W` vscode's autocompletion tried to match it with constants on tkinter library, when you proceed to autocomplete the import was added automatically.

Comment: @Billy it seems that you are correct as it is the first item that is imported with autocomplete if I type W in edit mode. I don't recall doing that but seems like a logical explanation as the imported line ends up above the visual code in the window so I was not even seeing it imported at the time it happened.